# How to install "htop" without root previllege

Tags: ubuntu, installation, htop

I have searched online with no luck. Question is in title. So, is it possible? If it is possible, would you provide step-by-step procedure to install it? Thanks.
I am on Ubuntu 16.0.4

Comment: Also, while this question is very much ion topic here, we have sister sites for [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) and [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). Just fyi of the OP who is new

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can install [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html#linux-installers) (no sudo needed) via

```
$ wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
$ bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

and then install [htop](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/htop)

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge htop
```

Another option is to try this [gist](https://gist.github.com/octavifs/45e120c7abe9bf03c652f70260947344).

Comment: Even though I successfully installed htop locally and dont test this procedure yet, I would accept it as a solution and hope everyone find this usefull. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the prerequisites of a standard GNU autotools-based C toolchain and ncurses, you can compile from source and then install to somewhere you have write access to, like ~/.local.

Instructions in the repo README: https://github.com/htop-dev/htop